# Android Jetpack Compose Multiple Layer Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have multiple destination,and some of the destinations also have subsidiary destinations represented by a Navigation component to interact with.

```
NavigationBar {
    page1 {
        NavigationBar {
            innerPager1
            innerPager2
            .....     
        }
    }
    page2 {....}
}
```

I want only the part excluding the navigationBar (innerPager1 & 2) switching not the entire page (page1) , is this possible with navController? if possible how to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i fully understood your question but i would start from looking for the [documents](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material#scaffold) about `Scaffold` component. As you will see, you can integrate, among others, a `BottomBar` component that is the one you're looking for. To switch only the innerPage content you need to change the `innerPadding` content. This is a general schema:

```
@Composable
fun MyLayout() {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { MyBottomBar() }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        BodyContent(Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
    }
}
```

There are many possible approaches to change the `BodyContent`. I'm going to cite a couple of them:

- using `State` to switch the `@Composable` method called:

```
var selectedTab by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(BottomNavItemTab.TAB_1) }
...
...
innerPadding ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding())) {
when (selectedTab) {
                    BottomNavItemTab.TAB_1 -> Tab1_Screen()
                    BottomNavItemTab.TAB_2 -> Tab2_Screen()
                    BottomNavItemTab.TAB_3 -> Tab3_Screen()
                }
}
```

- using Navigation component. In this case i suggest you to read the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav) because they provide well detailed example.

Please keep in mind that you are not forced to use only one of these solutions but you can integrate both of them. I'm saying this because it's not trivial to achieve navigation for tabs with and without BottomBar together.

Comment: I do know how to implement changing content, but i would more prefer using Navigation library to achieve this if possible

Comment: Method one of my post is one method to implement changing content. You can use Navigation library as shown in docs (link in the post in method 2).